# what is a good search strategy to look for source code of a particular function in chrome/firefox repository?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm currently studying javascript.

Usually, when I study something, I would like to go into the details and look at source code and try to understand how things really work internally.

I tried to find the source code for `JSON.stringify` function and I have found two repositories (one for [chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/) and the other one for [firefox](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/)).

However, the source code repository is massive and I can't seem to find what I want. So I was just wondering, is there a good search strategy that assist in finding a particular thing in such massive repositories?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to use JavaScript, you'd be better of studying the ECMA standard and MDN. If you really want to learn how the different engines are written, which has very little to do with actually using JavaScript, it's probably easier to find the repos on Github and browser through those, here's [**V8**](https://github.com/v8/v8)

Comment: Here's the [JSON stringifier](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/json-stringifier.cc)

Comment: Here is an Unofficial V8 API Reference Guide ( the site is pretty cool ) . https://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/json-stringifier_8cc_source.html ;)

Comment: hi @adeneo, thanks for the heads up. Its just that when I was studying the `JSON.stringify` function recently, there was something on the MDN JSON.stringify page that I couldn't understand, so I thought maybe looking at the source code would help me understand how the function actually works. Btw, do you mind if I ask, how you were able to find the exact location? when I do github search in a particular repository, it usually give me hundreds of results and I have to go through them one by one. Do you have a smarter search strategy?

Comment: hi @DavidDomain, thanks for the tip! Will keep it in my bookmark =)

Comment: @Captain America You're wellcome. Finding a specific function works very well on this site and the dependency maps give a nice overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know too much about the Chrome source code, so I will partially answer this for the Firefox codebase. As you correctly identified, the latest Firefox source code lives [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/).

**Searching the Firefox codebase**

However, the repository itself isn't well suited for searching the codebase and looking up functions/implementations, unless you already know where you need to look :) For this reason, a couple of services were created to ease searching the Firefox codebase: [DXR](https://searchfox.org/) and [searchfox](https://searchfox.org/). Both tools have pros and cons and do their job fairly well.

**Looking up `JSON.stringify`**

Now, the tricky party. I know that the JS engine lives under the `js/src` directory (the [mdn docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/contributing/directory_structure.html#js.2Fsrc) say so!). And the `JSON` object is part of the set of builtin objects, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects). So my first [guess search](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=stringify&case=false&regexp=false&path=js/src/) tried to look for the `stringify` word in that directory. And I got lucky! Apparently, the [jsapi.h](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/bbc1c59e460a27b20929b56489e2e55438de81fa/js/src/jsapi.h#5343) header file mentions *"JSON.stringify as specified by ES5."* in a comment: the comment is for the `JS_Stringify()`, which has its implementation in the related [jsapi.cpp](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/bbc1c59e460a27b20929b56489e2e55438de81fa/js/src/jsapi.cpp#6191) file.

Let me know if that helps or you have further questions!